# hacker sending from hotmail, nothing stops it, not joe jobbing

Tags: email, security, passwords, hotmail

My partner's hotmail account was hacked. She changed the password. The account is still sending spam emails from the hacker.

Now, I know all the usual suggestions, and none of them are going to work. The only place this account is accessed from at any time is a laptop with no hard drive, running an up to date linux live cd. This means every boot is a clean system. No keyloggers or viruses of any kind are in operation. No device accessing the account has been compromised. The problem appears to be entirely at the server end. How do we fix it?

My current advice to her is going to have to be disable the account and avoid using hotmail if there is no workable solution. This is not a joe jobbing hack as the sent messages are in the sent folder.

Comment: Are you sure it's really being sent from Hotmail, and not just showing her name in the header "From" field?  The latter is far more common.  You should view the full header to be sure of the sending server.

Comment: I checked, and I searched who-is IP search to confirm. The header data shows a microsoft hotmail server. Specifically 65.55.116.109, or 65.55.116.74 (checking two separate examples of the hacker's messages)

Comment: sounds like a first! could be the password change is emailed to a recovery email address and that needs changing?  could be the passwords she is using are obvious or she emailed them to herself or something. Could be there is a god and he's having a laugh with you, that's how odd it is!

Comment: Also turn on two step authentication and delete all App passwords in case its already turned on. I don't think it would that easy to sabotage hotmail servers into sending spam email without any user/client side software intervention...

Answer (score 1):

Turn on two step authentication and if you already have it turned on, delete all app passwords.

I don't think it would that easy to sabotage hotmail servers into sending spam email without any user/client side software intervention. Are you sure the email account is not configured with any other device?